# How to find the line caused segmentation fault in c++ compiled program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

I am using `vim` for c++ programming. I have bound the compile command to `ctrl+c` in vim and I run it in another `tmux` pane by running `./main.out`. My problem is that when my c++ program gives me `segmentation fault` error, I don't know which line has caused the problem. But when I compiled and ran the program in `vscode`, it showed me the line that caused the error.
I'm seeking for a way to find out the lines that cause runtime errors like `segmentation fault` error while running the program's binary file in console.
This is an example output when I do `./main.out`:

```
[1]    24656 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./main.out
```

Comment: Run `gdb ./main.out`. Also, add `-ggdb3` when compiling the program.

Comment: Note that while gdb will pretty much immediately point out where the program crashed, a little detective work is often required to find the bug that led to the crash. Once you know where the program crashes, you'll want to place a breakpoint to stop the program before the crash to gather information about what lead to the crash. Use step to advance the program and print to display variables. Use what you learn from gdb to isolate the bug, because it is usually a lot easier to prove the fix for an isolated bug is correct.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, it looks i'm gonna have a tough time finding out how does gdb works :D

Comment: Worth the time spent learning. Debugger use is a vital programming skill. The debugger slots in close behind the compiler as the top programmer productivity tools.

Comment: See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/ or some other GDB manual/tutorial. Using an IDE might be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling the program, add the `-g` compiler flag, or even better `-ggdb3`, which will give you a much prettier output, by adding debugging symbols to the executable. Also, make sure that you compile with the `-O0` optimization level.

To actually debug the program, run `gdb ./main.out` to start the program in a debugging session. If you then run `r`, gdb will start executing the program, and then stop at the line that gives the segfault.

To figure out *how* you got to that point, run `bt` while in the debugging session, and you will get a backtrace, which will show you all the function calls that were made to get to the line of code that crashed.

You can of course do a lot more than this (and you will probably need to, since locating the source of an error is often only the first step). You can use `p` to print the values of variables, set watchpoints, and many more things. For a while now, gdb even ships with a full fledged python interpreter, so you can even write a python script for your custom debugging needs.

Learning how to use gdb can seem overwhelming at the start, but persevere, and I guarantee the effort will pay off big time :)

Comment: Important note: All too often the bug that caused the crash is nowhere near the crash site. Locating the the crash and investigating it is a very important early step, but it is only one step.

Answer (score -1):

Ditto on Adin
Also your code can crash due to a call in which the parameter/s are acceptable but cause the proverbial out of range protection fault from some library somewhere if you don't have those debug versions. If an assembly routine is used inside there, they can do some strange things.
So don't be afraid to add temporary code to help like finding a single call that crashes when 1,000,000 other calls to the same did not. 
Is why I like to use a lot of generated randoms if possible to test when you got it fixed.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?